# How to join two dataframes in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.

The first dataframe is A.

[image]

And the second dataframe is B.

[image]

Basically both dataframes have **AdId** fields. First dataframe has unique AdIds per row but the second dataframe has multiple instances of a single AdId. I want to get all the information of that AdId to the second dataframe.

I am expecting the output as follows

[image]

I have tried the following code

```
B.join(A, on='AdId', how='left', lsuffix='_caller')
```

But this does not give the expected output.

Comment: A clear explanation on merging: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas `concat`:

```py
result = pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, sort=False)
```

More on merging with pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes